# Proof that fixed points of a null field are zero

Tags: waves, mathematical-physics, acoustics, hologram

Suppose we have a scalar field $V$ (which can be acoustic pressure, or a scalar electric potential) that is a solution of the wave equation

$$\Box V(x,y,z,t) = 0$$

I am wondering if a fixed (non-oscillating) minimum of field potential $\textbf{r}_0=(r_x,r_y,r_z)$ can be constructed with incoming waveforms on the boundary, or if it can be shown mathematically that is not possible

The [Khirchhoff integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff_integral_theorem) provides certain ability to control fields inside a volume with sources on the boundary (holophony and acoustic levitation are based on this principle). But I am not sure what are the general restrictions that have the waveforms

I tried to build an argument assuming that the waveform is made by finite Fourier elements

$$f(x,t)=\sum_{k,\omega} \hat{f}(k,\omega) e^{-I(kx-\omega t)}$$

Assume that $x_0$ is a fixed point with $f(x_0,t) \ne 0$, this means that

$$\frac{\partial^{n} f(x,t)}{\partial t^n} \Bigg|_{x=x_0} = 0 $$

for all $n > 0$.

Now the part of the argument that leaves me unsure is to assume that since the function is only made of a finite sum, after taking enough derivatives I will have enough equations to prove that all coefficients should be zero, which would contradict the hypothesis $f(x_0,t) \ne 0$.

Can this argument be improved? Also it doesn't say much if approximate fixed points can last for a period of time (probably yes, but I don't know how to prove that either)

**A motivating example** for this problem would be that, if you could create a stable minimum of electric potential with electromagnetic waves, you could sustain pseudo-electrostatic confinement potential for charged ions in a prescribed point that is otherwise devoid of matter.

Comment: I would suggest to take this question over to math.SE as someone with a firm background in PDE theory might well be able to give a useful answer (in other words, this can easily be restated as a pure maths question, but you have to be more specific on your boundary conditions).

Comment: I thought about it, but since it is related to holophony and wavefield synthesis, I thought it would find more expertise on Physics.SE

Comment: There is a simple counterexample: Just add an off-set  $\tilde V = V + 1$. Then $\tilde V$ will be a solution of the equation (with other boundary conditions) and a static point $\vec r_0$ of $V$ with $V(\vec r_0, t) = 0$ for all $t$ will be a static point of $\tilde V$ with value 1. So the question is ill posed. Of course it is an interesting question, whether a point can be a minimum at all times in a field that is a solution of the wave equation (it is not even necessary that the minimum have a $t$-independent value).

Comment: I should add that the DC term of the Fourier expansion must be zero, since to synthetise a finite waveform with the Kirchhoff theorem, you need nonzero frequencies